# Probability of x between two random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Given are $Z_1, Z_2$ i.i.d. standard normal.

Find

$P[Z_1 < t < Z_2]$

I have difficulties with working out how I should split the condition.

Is $P[Z_1 < t < Z_2] = P[Z_1 < t, t < Z_2]$ or is some additional condition required?

### My question

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: Is $t$ a constant? I'd interpret the notation here so, but @NeilG's comment at emcor's answer considers a random $t$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question seems to be a self-study question, but since there is already an answer that attempts to fully answer the question, I provide a full answer assuming that $t$ is a constant.

Indeed, $P(Z_1 < t < Z_2) = P(Z_1 < t, t < Z_2)$. By the independence of $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ the joint probability is equal to the product of the marginal probabilities. Thus,
$$
P(Z_1 < t < Z_2) = P(Z_1 < t, t < Z_2) = P(Z_1 < t) P(t < Z_2) = \Phi(t) \{1 - \Phi(t)\} ,
$$
where $\Phi(\cdot)$ denotes the distribution function of the standard normal distribution.

If $t = 0$, then $P(Z_1 < t < Z_2) = 0.25$ as one would expect since events $\{Z_1 < t\}$ and $\{Z_2 > t\}$ are independent and both have probability $0.5$.

Answer (score 2):

As the variables are independent and standardnormal symmetric*, their joint probability equals the product of the marginals:

$P(Z_1<t<Z_2)=P(Z_1<t,Z_2>t)=\Phi_{\rho=0}(t,-t)=\Phi(t)\cdot\Phi(-t)=\Phi(t)((1-\Phi(t))$

*By the normal symmetry we have $\{Z>t\}=\{Z<-t\}$, and independence implies $\rho=0$.

Comment: Even though $Z_1$ is independent of $Z_2$, that doesn't mean that $Z_1<t$ is independent of $Z_2>t$.  Consider $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ as low-variance normals at -1, 1, and t is -10, 0, or 10 with equal probability.  According to your formula, the probability is around 4/9; in fact it should be around 1/3.

Comment: This can't be right since the result should be a probability and $1/\{2\Phi(t)\} > 1$ for $t < 0$.

Comment: Yes, I reedited it..

Comment: Please take a while to ponder and double check your answer. This is about the 4th different expression you provide as the answer.

Comment: This can't be right either since $P(Z_1 < t < Z_2) \neq P(Z_1 < t \mid Z_2 > t)$.

Comment: No, the answer $\Phi(t)$ is wrong because $\Phi(t) = P(Z_1 < t) \neq P(Z_1 < t < Z_2)$. Also, your argument is flawed since $P(Z_1 < 0 < Z_2) = 0.25$ not $0.5$.

Comment: Thank you for your diligent efforts. This answer still looks a little incomplete without some explanation of the notation "$\Phi_{\rho=0}(t,-t)$."  If it is intended to be the CDF of a bivariate Normal distribution with correlation $\rho$, then some intermediate steps seem to be missing, since no "$-t$" appears in the preceding expressions. What is the reason you introduced this object?  It seems to me you could dispense with it altogether and thereby make the reasoning a little clearer.

Comment: @whuber The normal distribution is always denoted with $\Phi$. I also wrote in the sentence that I use the symmetry property of the normal distribution, so $\{X>t\}=\{X<-t\}$.

Comment: Yes, but you are using "$\Phi$" in an unconventional sense: yours has two arguments and one parameter. This needs an explanation in order for people to follow your answer.  BTW, please stop repeating your flagging of this thread: your flags have been considered carefully and were denied with clear explanations as to why.  The other answer is *not* "plagiarism." The comment about needing to double-check your answer is constructive and it is still applicable.

Comment: The standardnormal distribution has only 1 parameter $\rho$ by its being, and any multivariate distribution is defined by the number of its arguments. Your comments are essentially questioning the definition of notation, which is like saying "Please say that "+" means addition".

Comment: I have edited your preceding comment which was flagged as being rude or offensive. This site lives through benevolent contributors who are all here to help improve a repository of long-lasting and thoughtful QAs. As a contributor, you are also expected to [treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you because we’re all here to learn, together](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).